# why adding items to array trough JQuery is different than adding it manually?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

this code is kinda working but I'm getting different output , like if I add items to array manually like `let thearray = ["Hello","World];` it will show this on console log : `(2) ["Hello", "World"]`
but when I'm adding items dynamically trough JQuery , it just shows the things I added , like this:
`Hello World` , no item numbers ,no brackets , just the text . why this happening and how can I fix that ?

```
{
   let thearray = [];
   $('input[type=text]').keyup(function(e){
      if(e.which == 13){

      thearray = $(this).val();
      console.log(thearray);
      }
   });
   
}
```

Comment: I would expect `$(this).val()` in a text input to be a string.  The output described suggests that string is "Hello World".  What exactly are you expecting to be different and why?

Comment: this statement `thearray = $(this).val();` is setting the variable 'thearray' to be a string - just because you initialized it as an array doesn't mean it will infer your assignment to be an array item. `thearray.push($(this).val());` will keep the array structure

Comment: You are overwriting the same value everytime. If you want to push into an array consider clearing the array or checking existing value and then using thearray.push($(this).val());

Comment: @David I think I should try `push` like @Tushar Shahi said , or the answer written down. try `push` and `val()` in my code and you will what I exactly mean

Comment: @Kinglish yes you right , thanks ❤

Comment: @TusharShahi Exactly . I saw that in answers , thanks 

Comment: Hours of attempts based on intuitions about your code can save 5 minutes of documentation reading. ;)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette where can I find it ?

Comment: Use the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference) search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are not "adding" an item to the array, you are overwriting it with a string.

Try `thearray.push( $(this).val() )` instead.

[.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) documentation.